# C++: How do you pass a file as an argument?

Tags: c++, file, arguments

I initialized and opened a file in one of the functions and I am supposed to output data into an output file. How can I pass the file as an argument so that I can output the data into the same output file using another function? For example :

```
void fun_1 () {
    ifstream in;
    ofstream outfile;
    in.open("input.txt"); 
    out.open("output.txt");

    ////function operates////
    //........
    fun_2()
}

void fun_2 () {
    ///// I need to output data into the output file declared above - how???
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second function needs to take a reference to the stream as an argument, i.e.,

```
void fun_1 () 
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream outfile;
    in.open("input.txt"); 
    out.open("output.txt");
    fun_2( outfile );
}

void fun_2( ostream& stream )
{
    // write to ostream
}
```

Comment: I am hving another problem ,, one of the functions i have i have to cin>> a integer but it doesnt appear in the output file, why is that, thanks for the response by the way

Answer (score 3):

Pass a reference to the stream:

```
void first() {
    std::ifstream in("in.txt");
    std::ofstream out("out.txt");
    second(in, out);
    out.close();
    in.close();
}

void second(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) {
    // Use in and out normally.
}
```

You can `#include <iosfwd>` to obtain forward declarations for `istream` and `ostream`, if you need to declare `second` in a header and don't want files that include that header to be polluted with unnecessary definitions.

The objects must be passed by non-`const` reference because insertion (for output streams) and extraction (input) modify the stream object.

Comment: I am hving another problem ,, one of the functions i have i have to cin>> a integer but it doesnt appear in the output file, why is that, thanks for the response by the way

Comment: @Shadi: So you have something like `int i; in >> i; out << i;`? The file won't be written until the output buffer is flushed, so you can say `out.close()` or use `out << std::flush` to ensure your data is written.

Comment: no actually I have cin>>i; out<<i; does that work or is there a problem with it

Comment: @Shadi: That's not enough information. You should ask a new question, and post the code that's giving you the error.

Comment: Why do we pass in the opened file but the function takes the reference of a file as an argument? Why isn't it second(std::istream in, std::ostream out) instead?

Comment: @Steven: Streams aren’t copiable objects, so we have to pass them using a referential type—either a reference (declared `f(istream& s)`, called `f(s)`) or a pointer (declared `f(istream* s)`, called `f(&s)`).

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference to the stream.